# Differences between IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate's Tomcat server plugin and Community's Smart Tomcat plugin - missing features in startup/connection tab

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I recently started a new job and find myself in a situation where I'm struggling to start a service developed in Spring. The service requires a startup script to run smoothly. Interestingly, my senior uses the Ultimate Edition of IntelliJ IDEA, while I'm using the Community Edition.

Upon investigating, I discovered that IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition comes with a "Smart Tomcat" plugin, but it appears to offer fewer features compared to the dedicated Tomcat server plugin available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. Particularly, I'm missing the capabilities provided in the "Startup/Connection" tab, which are present in the Ultimate version's Tomcat plugin.

I am aware of the limitations of the Community version, but I'm curious if there's a way to overcome this challenge and achieve similar functionality. Are there any alternative approaches, configuration settings, or additional plugins that I can leverage to enhance the "Smart Tomcat" plugin's startup and connection capabilities?

If you have faced a similar scenario or have insights into this matter, I would greatly appreciate any advice, workarounds, or suggestions you could provide. My objective is to optimize my development workflow as much as possible while working with the Community Edition of IntelliJ IDEA.

[screenshot of smart tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isN5U.png)
[ss of tomcat server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbZhT.png)

What I tried:

1. Configured the "Smart Tomcat" plugin in IntelliJ IDEA with appropriate settings.
2. Deployed my Spring application (war file) using the plugin's deployment feature.
3. Ran the "Smart Tomcat" server configuration.

What I expected:
I expected the "Smart Tomcat" plugin to successfully start the server, deploy my application, and make it accessible via the specified URL (e.g., http://localhost:8080/myapp).

What actually resulted:
Unfortunately, the server did not start as expected, and I encountered an error message indicating that the service failed to deploy. I checked the server logs, it show NullPointerException in Intializer Java Class  for loading the startup script containing properties files.

I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot this problem and whether there are alternative approaches or configurations that could help me achieve successful deployment and startup.

Comment: Why is your colleague using Ultimate, and you Community? Isn't your company providing you with an appropriate license?

Comment: If Smart Tomcat plugin doesn't work as expected in your project you could try building/running the project via Maven / Gradle directly, for example by configuring Tomcat Maven plugin https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven  and configure corresponding run configuration in the IDE under `Run | Edit Configurations...`

Comment: Your colleague is using Tomcat 9, which is JavaEE, you are using Tomcat 10 which is JakartaEE. Use Tomcat 9 instead of Tomcat 10. This has nothing to do with the Intellij version in use but using not compatible versions of Tomcat (JavaEE and JakartaEE are not compatible).

Answer (score 1):

I found Polaris Tomcat Server plugin is available in Intellij Idea Community Edition recently. You can find the usage on the plugin page and [this document](https://github.com/YingXingGuiHai/PolarisTomcatServer/tree/main#readme).
If you have further question, please let me know.